# How to get the mask area of an image?

Tags: python, mask, medical-imaging

I am working with CT images and trying to remove the noise. Original image as follows:

[image]

I created a mask of the region I needed and my code is as follows:

```py
def remove_noise(image): 
    segmentation = morphology.dilation(image, np.ones((1, 1, 1)))
    labels, label_nb = ndimage.label(segmentation)
    
    label_count = np.bincount(labels.ravel().astype(int))#
    label_count[0] = 0

    mask = labels == label_count.argmax()
 
    mask = morphology.dilation(mask, np.ones((1, 1, 1)))
    mask = ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes(mask)
    mask = morphology.dilation(mask, np.ones((1, 1, 1)))
    masked_image = mask * image
    return masked_image
```

[image]

Mask is a binary array with 0 & 1 values only, but the original image has intensities ranging from -1024 to 3071 (I don't want to normalize original image here).  When I do: `masked_image = mask * original_image` this is what I get (looks like intensities have changed):

[image]

But, the image I need is as follows (without the lines under the CT scan):

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Intensities cannot change if you multiply by either 0 or 1. either they keep the same or get to 0.

Comment: Yeah, but you see the resulting image is different than the original image.

Comment: To clarify, you are trying to leave the original CT unchanged other than removing the lines from the bed under the patient? Then you would want your mask to be 1 everywhere except where the bedlines are.

Comment: That's right, that's what I wanted. I included my code for generating the mask in the question. Why when multiplied by the mask (binary), the original intensities have changed in the mask region?